# Update all records in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

I currently have a table that is 17 columns wide and has 30 records.

Basically, it's a table from another site that I'm scraping and then inserting into MySQL table.

```
$html = str_get_html($newHTML); // get the HTML     
        $tdContents = ""; // declare variable
        $rowArray = array(); // declare array for records
        for ($j = 0; $j < 510; $j++) // loop through each TD element, 17 columns by 30 records so 510
        {
            $f = $html->find("td",$j); // get the td elements from the html
            $tdContents = $f->innertext; // get the text inside the td
            $rowArray[] = $tdContents; // store that text inside the array

            if ($j == 16 || $j == 33 || $j == 50 || $j == 67 || $j == 84 || $j == 101 || $j == 118 || $j == 135 || $j == 152 || $j == 169 || $j == 186 || $j == 203 || $j == 220 || $j == 237 || $j == 254 || $j == 271 || $j == 288 || $j == 305 || $j == 322 || $j == 339 || $j == 356 || $j == 373 || $j == 390 || $j == 407 || $j == 424 || $j == 441 || $j == 458 || $j == 475 || $j == 492 || $j == 509) // every 17 td elements
            {
                $comma_separated = implode("','", $rowArray); // seperate the array contents with commas and apostrophes, set up for mysql
                $comma_separated = "'" . $comma_separated . "'"; // add apostrophes to beginning and end of the string
                $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO standings_20112012 VALUES (".$comma_separated.")"); // insert the data into mysql
                $rowArray = array(); // clear the array, for the next record

            }
        }
```

Comments should explain fine. This generates a table 17 x 30 with all info I need. If I run this again, it'll insert another 30 records, which is bad. I want to only update/overwrite etc. the table that's already created. So there should only ever be 30 records in the table. I'm stumped with this however.

Any help?

Comment: First of all `if ($j == 16 || $j == 33 ...)` is `if(($j+1) % 17 == 0)`...

Comment: before every insert, check to see if  record already exists. If it does, check to see if you need to update. If not exists, insert.

Comment: mysql has a `replace command`

Comment: @xbonez while that would work it is a highly inefficient method for doing that.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski THANK YOU! It's way too early in the morning, I got lazy trying to figure out the easy way for that if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a primary key to your dataset that is unique.  Then change your mysql query to `INSERT IGNORE` and it will throw out the duplicates. Alternatively you can can also use a `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` if you need to update what you already have in the table.

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is the way to go based on the post title. The link to the syntax would probably be useful to the OP http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Would deleting the table then inserting the information work as well?
also, I'm not sure what field I would set as a primary key.

Comment: Just tested, it works. I'm not sure how efficient it is, but it's fine for now. There is a field "Rank" which is 1-30 and is unique. If I set that as a PK, what would I need to change in my code?

Comment: @jsquadrilla All a PK is a list of unique values.  So in theory you could use every field as the PK.  If you examine the data I'm sure you can find 3 or 4 (perhaps all) fields that create a unique value. Also there would be no change to your code to check for the PK except the SQL statement.  That is the power of doing it in the right place.

Comment: @MechSoftware I checked the link Ben provided, would I then have to specify which fields to update?

Comment: @Yes, you have to specify the fields to update.  i.e. if you need to update them all then you specify them all.  It all depends on your need/implementation.  If for say some of the information is static like perhaps a category, or type, you don't have to update that unless you think it is going to change. Seeing 'Standings' it might be something like a team name that doesn't need an update.  Follow?

Comment: If this answer was helpful for you could you please accept it.

Comment: No problem.  That is why I mentioned it.  Good luck!